# How to deploy to multiple servers on the load balancer?

Tags: load-balancing, continuous-deployment, udeploy

Let's say I have 8 servers connected to the same load balancer, currently with app v1.0. When version 1.1 comes in, what's the right process to do the deployment?

e.g. if I deploy to 4 servers at a time. So I take out 4 from the LB first, install the v1.1. Then what? Take out the other 4, (from here to next step is downtime?), get the first 4 in to LB, ...

I am using uDeploy to automate the deployment, don't know how this works extractly.

Comment: Also, if you need help specifically with uDeploy, you might want to add a tag for it. If it's irrelevant you are fine then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So without getting too specific... when dealing with load balancers, you want to direct traffic to your 4 non-updated servers while you update your other 4 soon to be updated servers. Once those are completed, redirect your new user traffic to the 4 updated sites. You can either wait for users to disconnect and reconnect to the new servers or force their disconnection. This can vary vastly depending on what type of application you have though.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to know!

Comment: @JirongHu if this answers your question, an accept would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are trying to configure blue green deployments as detailed below.

http://martinfowler.com/bliki/BlueGreenDeployment.html

You should also look up how to "drain" connections from the pool of nodes in the load balancer so users are disconnected gracefully and do not see intermittent errors.